# Updating a HABTM model associations only deletes the associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Creating new HABTM associations work just fine for me, but each time I try to update them, all the associations get deleted.

This is how my update action looks like.

```
def update
    params[:dish][:cuisine_ids] ||= []
    params[:dish][:diet_ids] ||= []

    @user = current_user
    @dish = @user.dishes_selling.find_by(:id => params[:id])

    @dish.cuisines = Cuisine.where(:id => params[:dish][:cuisine_ids]) ### (1) ###
    @dish.diets = Diet.where(:id => params[:dish][:diet_ids]) ### (1) ###

    if @dish
        respond_to do |format|
          if @dish.update(dish_params) ### (2) ###
            format.html { redirect_to dish_path(@dish), notice: 'Dish was edited.' }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
          end
        end
    else
        flash[:error] = "You can only edit your dish!"
        render :index
    end
end
```

My dish params looks like so

```
    def dish_params
      params.require(:dish).permit(:title, :desc, cuisine_ids: [:id], diet_ids: [:id])
    end
```

If on edit I click on two checkboxes of cuisine, the logs while on step (2) reads this (Note only `Delete` and no update or Insert for `cuisine_dishes` table)

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "cuisines_dishes" WHERE "cuisines_dishes"."dish_id" = ? AND "cuisines_dishes"."cuisine_id" IN (7, 9)  [["dish_id", 61]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "dishes" SET "desc" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "dishes"."id" = 61  [["desc", "yema1245"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-12 06:57:36.622811"]]
   (5.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dishes/61
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 13.7ms)
```

**Question** : Why does updating HABTM associations try to delete the association, instead of trying to create new ones if they do not previously exist, and delete if they previously existed but do not any more.

Comment: can you accept the answer if it is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using the << operator instead of = ;

```
@dish.cuisines << Cuisine.where(:id => params[:dish][:cuisine_ids]).last
```

This should add and not replace the required ids in both the tables.

Comment: oh and because you are quereing by id, you can just use find:
`Cuisine.find(params[:dish][:cuisine_ids])`
cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is born from a question I have:

> Why does updating HABTM associations

What do you mean by *updating HABTM associations*?

---

**HABTM**

HABTM associations are a [collection of records](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) which are available to add (`<<`), or remove (`.delete`). You can't "update" a record with this - you either have to add or delete (mainly because they don't have `primary keys`.

We do that in this way:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def update
   @obj = Model.find params[:id]
   @obj2 = Model2.find params[:model_2]

   @obj.asssociative_data << @obj2
end
```

The problem you have is you're passing new data to your `habtm` association. The *only* way you can "update" this data is to overwrite all the current collection with the new `ids` you've posted (which is what I think you're doing)

---

**Fix**

The way to fix this will be to make sure you're passing the correct params in your `cuisine_ids: [:id]`, `diet_ids: [:id]` `strong_params` method.

I think your problem will be that you're passing `:id` only. I think Rails expects you to pass `:cuisine_ids` and `:diet_ids`, with those arrays populated with numerical data only, like with our code:

```
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(attributes(Profile), :image, :category_ids)
end
```

To do this, you'll have to do this with your form:

```
<%= f.select(:category_ids, Category.all, prompt: "Category") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now understand that my expectation was incorrect and I now can correctly "update" my associations. But I still see `SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "cuisines_dishes"` made on `@dish.update(dish_params)`. How do i prevent those deletions on that step?